# MediaElement Windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I have a weird bug here and i don't know how to call this,but here's the thing.. i have my MediaElement in my XAML ->> `<MediaElement  Height="10" Width="10" x:Name="Nomes"/>` and i have a Button to call that Element which is mp3 audio, and works fine C# ->>

```
private async void AMN(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Nomes.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///Sounds/AMN.mp3", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
        Nomes.Play();
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        VibrationDevice vb = VibrationDevice.GetDefault();
        vb.Vibrate(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(AmericaDoNorte));

    }
```

Here is my SecondPage Override Method

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        HardwareButtons.BackPressed += HardwareButtons_BackPressed;
    }

    void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        if(rootFrame == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (rootFrame.CanGoBack)
        {
            rootFrame.GoBack();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

And when the Vibrate Method is call i navigate through a new page,and works fine,but when i comeback to that page, the audio which supposed be to play when i hit the button play by yourself without i click, how this is possible? Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing you're testing your app in debug mode? If so then try deploying your app and try. In debug mode the OS often keeps a `MediaElement` instance alive even when you navigate away from the page or when the app suspends (this doesn't happen when you're actually running your app because the `MediaElement` doesn't support background playback).

Answer (score 0):

I guess your MediaElement property **AutoPlay** is enabled. Go to properties and have a look.
Hope this helps.
Thanks!